# getItem method in FragmentStatePagerAdapterdoesn't work correctly

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I want to implement swipe between MyFragments, but there is a problem with getItem method in FragmentStatePagerAdapter class, this method didn't allow me to return MyFragment instead of Fragment! because I use android.app.Fragment instead of  android.support.v4.app.Fragment

is there any class like FragmentStatePagerAdapter don't extends android.support.v4.app?